# Android Studio выдает ошибку при запуске

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

При загрузке нового проекта и при его дальнейшем открытии выдается ошибка такого формата в `Event Log`:

> 17:21:20 NullPointerException: null

Что делать?

Comment: Добавьте к уопросы вывод лога ошибки...

Answer (score 4):

Попробуй открыть диспетчер задач и посмотреть не висит ли у тебя в памяти уже запущенный проект(если висит, то снеси его), такое иногда происходит

Answer (score 3):

Это рантайм ошибка. Так как было обращение к "нулевому" обьекту. К какому именно можно узнать запустив дебагер и посмотрев где вылетает `NPE`. Или же детально посмотреть логи - зачастую этого достаточно для определения где ошибка.